# How to parse the response of youtube video upload api to get the video's url

Tags: android

I'm using the youtube api's non resume method to upload a video to youtube from my android app. The response of this upload is an xml file. I need to parse it and find the url of the video (WHICH IS IN THE TAG media:player url). How to get that url?

The xml is as follows

[image: XML is as follows]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to parse that XML using the string manipulation methods. That thing was a success as I need only the url. I manipulated the string as follows

```
int start = youtubeXml.indexOf("<media:player url='");
String urlPart = youtubeXml.substring(start);
youtubeUrl = (String) urlPart.subSequence(urlPart.indexOf("http"), urlPart.indexOf(";feature"));
```

Here youtubeXml is a String which contains the String representation of the output data stream

Comment: XPath should have been your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The video ID is under:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[id is here]

You can start an android VIEW activity for the URL: "http://youtube.com/[video id]" which will launch the default YT player with the video (or ask the user to chose a player from a list).

Comment: I kno the video id is present in the tag id. also the video url is available in the media:group. But I have some problems in parsing the xml response. I tried Dom parser, Xml pull parser and saxfeed parser. All giving an error message. So now I convereted the xml stream to string and cropped the media url